# Class properties: Access child class properties in parent constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

I would like to build a ES6 class which can read it's child properties already on constructor level. In the other words I would like to have this specs passing:

```
class Collection {
  model = 'model';

  constructor() {
    // I JUST DO A SIMPLE ASSIGNMENT HERE
    // BUT IN THE FINAL VERSION I WOULD
    // LIKE TO DO SOME MORE ADVANCED
    // CALCULATIONS HERE
    this.modelCopy = this.model;
  }

  getModel() {
    return this.model;
  }
}

class MyCollection extends Collection {
  model = 'myModel';
}

it('this is passing', () => {
  expect(new Collection().getModel()).toBe('model');
  expect(new MyCollection().getModel()).toBe('myModel');
});

it('this is NOT passing', () => {
  expect(new Collection().modelCopy).toBe('model');
  // this fails because new MyCollection().modelCopy === 'model'
  expect(new MyCollection().modelCopy).toBe('myModel');
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the current behavior and what is the expected one? Are the assertions the former? Then what is the latter.

Comment: Also `model = 'myModel';` is not valid JS

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev the current behavior is that `new MyCollection().modelCopy` returns `'model'`. While I would like to get `myModel`.

@skyboyer answer seems to explain the issue clearly. I can't achieve what I want with class properties.

I will need to think about different construction.

Comment: If you are using class properties then your not using ES6.

Answer (score 1):

class properties are not handled natively. So far they are transformed by babel's [`plugin-proposal-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties).

And if this plugin transpiles class properties into values are initialized *after* `constructor()` is called there is nothing you can do about that.

I've [found an issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8510) in their github that cleary states for this approach:

> Yes. It can't be done before calling `super()` because this is the return value of super. Before, this doesn't exists so class fields can't be defined.

[UPD] spec is here: [tc39proposal-class-fields](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/) but I've failed to find out information if such approach is proposed to follow in native implementation or not.